# Using Python script in nodejs app on openshift

Tags: python, node.js, openshift, lxml

I'm using `openshift` to deploy my bot written in `nodejs`. I already used `Python` as a script in my project and it worked fine, but now when I'm trying to use `html` from `lxml` library. It's not possible to use it and I don't have the permission to install it. Is there any work around?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm trying to install it via ssh, but pip command is not found because I'm using Nodejs app on openshift. Is there any more information I can provide?

Comment: What do you need pip for? Python has a built in xml parser if you can't get lxml

Comment: You cannot install anything?